# Does Cheer have any effect on TinkerBell?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

Tinkerbell is not a normal summon, as she doesn't get rid of Donald and Goofy, and sticks around until the end of the fight. The description of cheer is

> Increases the summons' MP gauge, giving them more time and attacks per battle. Equip to entire party to boost effect.

Tinkerbell, however, doesn't have a visible MP gauge, doesn't have attacks, and doesn't go away when out of MP. So does cheer have any effect at all on Tinkerbell? If so, what effect does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description can be taken at face value:  Cheer's only effect is to increase the size of your summon's MP gauge (in fact the Japanese name for the ability literally is "Summon MP Up").  As Tinkerbell doesn't have a personal MP gauge, Cheer doesn't do a thing for her.